# Passing objects/datas from library to console app (how to)

Tags: c++, events, signals

I want to make a event-handling like system in c++. I have tried to create something like that;

```
###Library
class manager
{
public:
   void init(void i) { x = i };
   void fire()
   {
      x("test");
   }
private:
   void x;
};
```

(space)

```
###Console App
void tester(char* i)
{
   printf("%c", i);
}
int main()
{
   manager m;
   m.init(tester);
   m.fire();
   return 0;
}
```

Yes, I now that is completely wrong way but I need something like that. I'm newbie and I can't understand why I can't make something like that.

Comment: Use `std::function`. Also, C++ is not "scripting".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for function pointers. Something like this:

```
typedef void (*EventFunc)(char*);

class manager
{
public:
   void init(EventFunc callback) { x = callback };
   void fire()
   {
      x("test");
   }
private:
   EventFunc x;
};
```

The rest of your code should work unchanged (except that `printf("%c", i);` should be `printf("%s", i);`).